# how to remove unwanted spaces and new line characters

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a text area for entering multiple email addresses.I texted the mail id like below image.I received the value from text area to the string and i got like that  for "a@a.com\r\n\r\na@ac.om\r\n\r\nb@b.com\r\n        k@k.com"

And i need to save this data to the table as comma separated email ids.
eg:**a@a.com,,a@a.com,b@b.com ,k@k.com**[image]

And i get that the 
How can i remove the unwanted newline characters and spaces from the string.

Comment: `Split()` first, then `Trim()`, specifying to trim spaces, newline and carriage return characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Split` and `Join` with a little bit of *Linq*:

```
  string source = "a@a.com\r\n\r\na@ac.om\r\n\r\nb@b.com\r\n k@k.com";

  // a@a.com,a@ac.om,b@b.com,k@k.com 
  string result = string.Join(",", source
    .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(line => line.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [string.Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to join together a list of emails separated by a comma, the list of emails is generated by LINQ.

```
var emails = @"a@a.com\r\n\r\na@ac.om\r\n\r\nb@b.com\r\n k@k.com";

var result = string.Join(",", emails
    .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    .Select(x => x.Trim()));
```

Output of result:

> a@a.com,a@ac.om,b@b.com,k@k.com

Comment: Counter example: if eMail contains *space* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part - "..*space* and "(),:;<>@[\] characters are allowed with restrictions .."), e.g. `"my address@myMail.com"` the address will be erroneously *splitted* into two.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Another good point. Wrote a new one to fix it, panicked and deleted it, rolled back and by that time saw that yours was better anyway. +1 from me ;-)

Comment: no need to panic, just routine testing :) the final tip: `char`s are usually more *readable* and *faster* then `string`s: `.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, ...`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that. Will remember it for next time.